# Prevent a Man-In-The-Middle attack whilst transmitting a PSK for first time

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-exchange, man-in-the-middle

I'm developing a network where two parties that want to join both compute ephemeral ECC keys for a key exchange, to create an encrypted connection. I plan to authenticate these keys by signing them with a pre-shared ECC key. However, how should these PSKs be transmitted in a secure way to prevent MITM attacks that change the PSKs??

Comment: A pre shared key has to be transmitted using a method that lacks any man in the middle.  For example, IT might run a kiosk from which they distribute packages of signing keys used by the corporation (x509 for TLS, perhaps SSH key fingerprints, etc).

Comment: "transmitting a PSK for first time" - if a key is pre-shared, it means both side already have it. What are you going to transmit for the first time?

Comment: @mentallurg for both parties to have the PSK then it must be transmitted at 1 point so that they both have it, otherwise it wouldn't be shared

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson, so if there was a decentralised network and a new node joins, and publishes his signing ECC key to a DHT on the network, how can this key be shared to the DHT without a man in the middle??

Comment: Welcome to one of the fundamental issues in information security.  You must have a pre-existing secret of some sort - you can not bootstrap from zero without a trusted communication channel.

Comment: Must have pre-existing _unforgeable_ information, not _secret_ information.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Curious use of terms, what does it mean to have unforgeable information?  Is that term an accepted nomenclature for knowledge that can produce a ZKP?  I'm just surprised to see the concept of "unforgeable information" and feel I must have missed something.

For the difference between my meaning of secret vs your phrase I think it depends what scope the discussion is taking.  Certainly there must be _a_ secret.  It need not be held by everyone (ex: PKI) and I'm not meaning secret in a strictly information theoretic sense (ex: number theoretic).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson When you said ‘pre-existing secret’ I read that as ‘pre-_shared_ secret’, sorry.  What I meant is that Alice must know something about Bob that an adversary cannot forge; otherwise Alice can't distinguish Bob from the adversary.  You are right that there have to be secrets too, of course—all I meant is that the secrets don't have to be shared in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic solution. Either both parties are in a direct contact to exchange a PSK, or they use authentication based on PKI. Otherwise there is no guarantee that there is no man in the middle.